# Are these two statements equivalent? (from NerdDinner tutorial)

Tags: sql, linq

Basically I want to know if the two statements below are ultimately exactly the same.  The NerdDinner tutorial states that IQueryable<> objects won't query the database until we attempt to access/iterate over the data or call ToList on it.  So aside from returning the same exact items do the two statements below also PERFORM the same as far as querying the database is concerned?  If I had a million records, would one be better than the other?

I have the following statement:

```
    return from party in entities.Parties
           where party.PartyDate > DateTime.Now
           orderby party.PartyDate
           select party;
```

is that the same as:

```
    return entities.Parties.Where(p => p.PartyDate > DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will perform exactly the same, yes - aside from the ordering. With a very slight change, they will compile into *exactly* the same code:

```
// Extension method syntax
return from party in entities.Parties
       where party.PartyDate > DateTime.Now
       orderby party.PartyDate
       select party;

// Query expression
return entities.Parties
               .Where(party => party.PartyDate > DateTime.Now)
               .OrderBy(party => party.PartyDate);
```

Note that as well as adding the `OrderBy`, I've also changed the name of the lambda expression parameter name to match that in the query expression.

Effectively the compiler transforms the first block into the second block before applying all the normal compilation steps. You can think of query expression support as being a bit like a preprocessor step.

I wrote about this in more detail in my Edulinq blog series, in [Part 41: How Query Expressions Work](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx).

Comment: @Saeed: A large part of the point of writing blog posts and articles is so that I can put the effort in *once* to explain things in significant detail, and then refer to them from answers like this.

Comment: Sounds great Jon. I learned something by reading your blog. (first comment was just joke:)

Answer (score 0):

***Yes***, except the top one orders. Performance is pretty much on a par except for that.

First one is LinQ syntax, second one is a Lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

YES. They are both the same, only the first one orders the results whereas the second one does no ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement converted to lambda form would look like this:

```
return entities.Parties
               .Where(p => p.PartyDate > DateTime.Now)
               .OrderBy(p => p.PartyDate)
               .Select(p => p);
```

As far as performance is concerned, the query comprehension syntax is converted to the lambda syntax by the compiler; it's simply syntactic sugar. They perform equally because they're compiled to the same expression.